# Java Restful Service eclipse tomcat HTTP Error 404

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, jersey-2.0

i try to keep up with a java rest service. So i found some tutorials, which explain always the same way. But i cant get this running :(.

I made Dynamic Web Project in Version 2.5 and Tomcat 7.0 in eclipse. Then i load following jars to WEB-INF/lib

[image]

My Projectname is com.freespots.rest. I created following web.xml

[image]

Ok now iam going to create the java-class right? Well i did it Java Resources/src/com.freespots.rest.service:

[image]

If i start Tomcat and type url to my browser like localhost:8080/com.freespots.rest the Tomcat shows my index.html file.
But if i go to url localhost:8080/com.freespots.rest/api/hello there is just a HTTP 404 Error:
[image]

Well iam new to Java Webdevelopment and i cant figure out my Problem. I hope some guy can explain my mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the old (1.x) Jersey configuration. In Jersey 2.x, the class namescpaces and property names have changed. You should instead use

```
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    ...
```

See other deployment options [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet)

Answer (score 0):

**localhost:8080/com.freespots.rest** this URL will run welcome page which is index.html as you said, and **`localhost:8080/com.freespots.rest/api/hello`** here no page found so 404 not found error. Try to put **`@Path("name")`** above method and call **`localhost:8080/com.freespots.rest/api/hello/name`**

Comment: That's not true, since you are doing a GET request on the path /hello, the method with the '@GET' annotation will be executed if no '@Path' is specified.