# Tomcat 7.0 + Chrome dont show JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, tomcat, jersey

Iam using Dynamic Web Project 2.5, Jersey and Tomcat 7.0 to create a Java Restful Webservice. I want to response JSON if someone request data. But i always get the following error from Tomcat:

[image]

That my configurations in relation to web.xml and annotations are ok is demonstrated by using xml instead of JSON. Then its working fine:

[image]

If i switch MediaType Notation from APPLICATION_XML to APPLICATION_JSON the error is thrown.

Iam using Chrome-Browser and i read that chrome just show a json-string if requested. I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the Java code of your method ?

Comment: check your server log, looks like the json serializer is not defined corectly.

Comment: Not sure the reason for the 500. I would imagine you would get a 415 with no JSON support. But you can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30424031/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet yeah the dependencies was missing. Thanks. Post as answer and i will accept it. SOLVED :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30767165/2587435), you seem to missing a [provider](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html) for JSON/POJO support. You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424031/2587435) for all the jars and dependencies you need to add to your project.

<sub>**Note:** The linked answer shows 2.17 jars for Jersey, but you are using 2.18. The answer also provides a link where you can download the version you need.</sub>

Comment: Nice! Cross questions catch!